# input string comes in variety of separating delimiter, how to check for the right one?

Tags: c#, split, delimiter

i have a small problem.
i am working on a keywords string, which comes from different providers (which i have no control over), and they all send the string in a different format.

the keywords in the string could be separated by commas, semicolons, space, or tab.
in one string, only one type of the delimiters is used.

how would you go about of recognizing it?

i was thinking of something like (pseudo code):

```
string delimiters = { ",",";"," " };

var x = str.split(delimiters[0]).count();

var y = str.split(delimiters[1]).count();

var z = str.split(delimiters[2]).count();
```

then check which is the largest and use it.

do you have know a better idea ?

Comment: I like your idea - try each one and check which gives the sanest result.

Comment: Do you know the correct field count?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - no. it can have 1 - 50 keywords. but nothing promised.

Comment: Note that in soem cases the "most popular" delimiter won't be best - e.g. `Bobsson, Bob;Davisson, David;Charlsson, Charlie` or `red one;green one;blue one`.

Comment: @Rawling yes, i know there are a lot of corner cases, that is why i posted the question, to try and dig out all the problems before i get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea works perfectly but I think a better solution could be create an extension method and return a jagged array in this way:

```
public static class Utilities {
    public static string[ ][ ] MultipleSplit( this string s, char[ ] delimiters ) {
        string[][] result = new string[ delimiters.Length ][ ];
        for ( int i = 0; i < delimiters.Length; i++ )
            result[ i ] = s.Split( delimiters[ i ] );

        return result;
    }

    public static string[ ] Larger( this string[ ][ ] jaggedArray ) {
        int index_larger = 0;

        for ( int i = 0; i < jaggedArray.Length; i++ ) {
            if ( jaggedArray[ i ].Length > jaggedArray[ index_larger ].Length )
                index_larger = i;
        }
        return jaggedArray[ index_larger ];
    }
}
```

And then use it like here:

```
string[][] result = str.MultipleSplit(delimiters);
string[] larger = result.Larger();
```

Comment: +1 for the nice code, i wrote only pseudo code since im not sure yet on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
var result = str.Split(new[] {',', ';', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Edit:

```
var result = delimiters.Select(d => str.Split(d))
            .OrderByDescending(l => l.Count())
            .First();
```

Comment: he is not sure that which one is right delimiter to split the string with.

Comment: This overload of [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) means: "take any of these". But OP wants to take a specific separator he doesn't know yet.

Answer (score 0):

try doing a split with a regular expression. A regex for that would be [,;\s]. This would look for commas, semicolons spaces OR tabs.

Comment: This still will not tell me which one is the "winner"

Answer (score 0):

while the suggestions here are acceptable and meet your current need, the fundamental problem is

> which comes from different providers (which i have no control over),
>   and they all send the string in a different format.

You need some form of a "contract" or agreement with the various providers on how to accept their information. Even if each one is different the system can determine who is submitting the data and choose the correct parser.

One thing none of the current options offer is a way to ensure you have good data. what if the data submitted is bad? how you will you know? Does it matter if the data is bad?

Comment: Its hard for me to believe i can convince the owners of "Photoshop", "FotoStation" and some other softwares to agree on one format.
also, since you are talking about 1000's of photographers submiting their works, i cannot force them to buy one type of software when they have been working for years with another.
since the software i build is manualy operated, the person can see the results and see if it contains 'bad' data.

Comment: this wasn't clear in the OP. and i'm not suggesting the power players should or would follow your custom format. however, you do have standard formats for each piece of software and part of the import process could be selecting the source of information.

Comment: im sorry if i sounded rude, that was not the intention.
i cant control the incoming data, if i could, i would have never posted this question. even if i will look for each and every metadata editor software and understand their input it will still not help me, since i do not know what the photosgraphers will upload. they upload images in bulk to ftp, and provide a csv file. they do no have any kind of interface where i could ask them for the format, neither they understand it, sometimes it is just raw output from their camera which includes a csv.